# What files of Laravel Elixir are necessary on production server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir

**Intro:**
Gulp watches my css/js files till development mode on my local machine.

Then on production stage I upload all laravel project on production (live) server.

**Problem:**
With all that gulp and elixir stuff installed laravel project becomes very heavy.

**Question:**
What files of `node_modules` directory do I exactly need to load with project on production server to make Elixir works fine?

I mean including `all.css` and `all.js` files by

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/all.css') }}">`

Maybe there is no need to load all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about including any files from the `node_modules` directory; you can think of those as dependencies similar to the `vendor` directory for your php project.

You'll just need to include the files in the `public/*` directory in order to have working views if you are using the default paths and configuration for compiling assets. You can see a good example of this in the [**Scripts** section of the Elixir documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#working-with-scripts).

> The scripts method assumes all paths are relative to the resources/assets/js directory, and will place the resulting JavaScript in public/js/all.js by default:
>
> `elixir(function(mix) {
>           mix.scripts([
>               'jquery.js',
>               'app.js'
>           ]);
>       });`

As a side note, I personally wouldn't recommend creating this sort of separation because the project seems *heavy*. If you have a very large project size, it most likely shouldn't be due to css and js. You can also consider using a cdn to lighten the production space if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem. 
My gulpfile.js has

```
mix.sass('app.scss');
mix.browserify('app.js');
mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
```

This is my solutions:

- Option 1: If you have npm and gulp on server. On local machine, do
  `npm shrinkwrap`, then push package.json, gulpfile.js, npm-shrinkwrap.json,
  resources/assets/(js|sass). In server website root, do `npm install` and `gulp --production`
- Option 2: No need npm or gulp on server. Just do `gulp --production` on local and push public/build/* to server. If Elixir versioning is not used, push public/(js|css) instead. resources/assets(js|css) and all npm gulp stuff can be kept from server.

`node_modules` is not needed in either case.
I used option 2, much easier and worked fine for me.